# Proving dimension equality involving linear transformation and it's conjugate transpose over inner product spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

Let $W, V$ inner product spaces, and $T: V \to W$. Let $T^*: W\to V$ the conjugate transpose of $T$, which means:
$$
\left<Tv,w\right>=\left<v,T^*w\right>,\forall v\in V,w\in W
$$
I need to prove the following equality:
$$
\dim\ker T^*=\dim\ker T+\dim W-\dim V
$$

So I defined the following:
$$
T^*T: V \to V \\
TT^*: W \to W
$$
We know that:
$$
\dim V=\dim \ker T^*T + \dim \text{Im}T^*T\\
\dim W=\dim \ker TT^* + \dim \text{Im}TT^*
$$

Now let $v \in \ker T^*T$. Then $T^*Tv=0 \Rightarrow Tv\in\ker T^*$. So we conclude:
$$
0=\left<T^*Tv,v\right> = \left<Tv,Tv\right> \Rightarrow Tv=0 \Rightarrow v\in \ker T \\
\Rightarrow\ker T^*T\subseteq \ker T
$$
Let $v\in\ker T$, then $T^*Tv=T^*(0)=0 \Rightarrow v\in\ker T^*T \Longrightarrow \ker T^*T=\ker T$. The same goes for $\ker TT^*=\ker T^*$.

Combining all together:
$$
\dim V=\dim \ker T + \dim \text{Im}T^*T\\
\dim W=\dim \ker T^* + \dim \text{Im}TT^*
$$

All that is left to show is that
$$
\dim \text{Im}T^*T = \dim \text{Im}TT^*
$$

But this is where I struggle, I couldn't find a way to prove that last equality.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you even started considering $T^*T$. Just use the fact that $\dim \operatorname{Im}(T) = \dim \operatorname{Im}(T^*)$ along with
$$
\dim V = \dim \ker T + \dim \text{Im} T,\\
\dim W = \dim \ker T^* + \dim \text{Im} T^*.
$$

Comment: You could use $T^*T$ in order to show that $\dim \operatorname{Im}(T) = \dim \operatorname{Im}(T^*)$ if you want. In particular, you have already shown that $\dim \ker T = \dim \ker T^*T$. Now, note that $\operatorname{Im}(T^*) \subset \operatorname{Im}(T^*T)$, so that 
$$
\dim \operatorname{Im}(T^*) \leq \dim \operatorname{Im}(T^*T) \leq \dim \operatorname{Im}(T),
$$
so that $\dim \operatorname{Im}(T) \leq \dim \operatorname{Im}(T^*)$. It follows from there that $\dim \operatorname{Im}(T^*) \leq \dim \operatorname{Im}(T^{**}) = \dim \operatorname{Im}(T)$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you for the answer. Part of the exercise I'm solving is to prove that $\dim\text{Im} T= \dim\text{Im} T^*$ so I would like to use your advice in your first comment but I need to prove that equality first. For your second comment, it is not clear to me why $\text{Im} T^* \subset \text{Im} T^*T$. If $v \in \text{Im} T^*T$ then there exist $u \in V$ such that $T^*T(u)=v$, which means $v \in \text{Im} T^*$, so it seems that $\text{Im} T^*T \subset \text{Im} T^*$.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that backwards, it should be $\operatorname{Im} T^* \supset \operatorname{Im} T^*T$, and similarly $\dim \operatorname{Im} T^* \geq \operatorname{Im} T^*T = \operatorname{Im} T$. Again, the fact that $\dim \operatorname{Im} T^* \geq \dim \operatorname{Im} T$ in general implies that $\dim \operatorname{Im} T^{**} \geq\dim \operatorname{Im} T^*$, so that the two images are equal in dimension

Comment: Another way: Note that
\begin{align*}
w \in \ker T^* &\iff T^*w=0 \\
&\iff \forall v \in V \ \ \langle v,T^*w \rangle=0 \\
&\iff \forall v \in V \ \ \langle Tv,w \rangle=0 \\
&\iff \forall u \in \operatorname{im} T \ \ \langle u,w \rangle=0 \\
&\iff w \in (\operatorname{im} T)^\perp.
\end{align*}
So, $\ker T^* = (\operatorname{im} T)^\perp$.